# How to tell if a git merge was fast-forwardable or not

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a feature branch that I am merging via Github PR (git merge --no-ff).

What I would love is the ability to tell if the merge was fast-forwardable when it was merged.  Essentially, all my tests run on the feature branch.  I would like skip running my tests on the main branch if it's running against basically the same code.

If there was a commit added to the main branch while the feature branch was being developed, though, merging should cause my tests to run.  Is that possible with git?

Answer (score 2):

To know if a revision is fast-forwardable from any given point, you could try using `git branch --contains`. If branch A is fast-forwardable from point B, then branch A should list on `git branch --contains point-B` (use -r if branch A is on a remote).

Answer (score 0):

The output of `git merge` tells you when it uses a fast-forward merge. You can keep local versions of both branches, merge your local feature branch into your local master, and look at the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally test whether some existing merge commit *M* (where *M* is the hash ID) *could* have been a fast-forward operation by testing whether `M^1` is an ancestor of `M^2`:

```
...--o--o--M^1---M--...
      \         /
       o--o--M^2
```

(this merge was not fast-forward-able as the first parent of *M*, `M^1`, is not an ancestor of the second parent of *M) 
vs:

```
...--M^1-----------M--...
        \         /
         o--o--M^2
```

(this merge was fast-forward-able, but was forced to be a real merge).

For test-skipping purposes, however, it might be simpler to compare the trees associated with `M^1` and *`M`*.  That is, even if there was a real merge, it could have been a "no-effect merge".  A tree comparison would find this, while ancestor testing would not (you'd run an unnecessary test).